# Java recursive method set index of array to +1 and after call -1

Tags: java, recursion, methods

i have a question.How i can change a index of array in method to +1 on first call and after the first call -1 again in a recursive method? 
For example i need the index of Array on first call 12, after second call 13 and next call 12 again.

Comment: Let's know what you're going to do with this result along with some code snippets you've tried so far, so we can help you. Happy coding!

Comment: I find your question difficult to understand. What do you mean by "change the index"?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void diluent(int maxwert, int volwert, int wert, int waitingTime) {
for (c = wert; c <= maxwert / volwert;) {
                String a = pumptocom() + " " + volwert;
                log.setLogMessage(5, volwert + ""); 
                int b = timerCaller(start, rt, a, waitingTime,txt[12]);
```

> ---> after i call the method again i will change the index of array txt[]
>   from 12 to 13 and after the next call from 13 to 12 and again.

```
            if (b == 0) {
                timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        diluent(maxwert, volwert, wert + 1, waitingTime);
                    }
                }, waitingTime * 1000);
```